# Active Questions: Bookmark to 'modified n mins ago'

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Active Questions** shows 'modified n mins ago' against each question.

However, when you click on the question, it takes you to the top of page, not the bookmark where the question was 'modified n mins ago'.

Compare with the link provided in notifications that takes you to the corresponding bookmark on the page.

Similarly to the above, 'modified n mins ago' can have a link under it pointing to the appropriate bookmark, while the question title can stay as now.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the question, it does indeed take you to the top of page, **but**

if you click on the *'modified n mins ago'* hotspot, it goes straight to the actual item modified.

Answer (score 1):

The "modified" link works correctly for me, and as designed.
To understand how that link works, it is necessary to understand when a question is considered modified. A question is considered modified, when:

- The question has been edited
- The question gets a new answer
- An answer for that question has been edited

As "special" case, a created question is considered "modified."

In all these cases, the "modified" link takes to the post that has been modified.

For example, the first four active questions are currently the following ones:

[image: screenshot]

In the first question shown there, the "6s ago" link takes to the question, because I have edited the question itself, ["Having influence" in perfect tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58749/having-influence-in-perfect-tense). In the second question, the "11m ago" link takes to [the answer given from simchona](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58765/usage-of-hypocrite/58766#58766) for https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58765/usage-of-hypocrite.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the helpfully detailed explanation. In fact, I will comment again after reading through carefully one more time.